# Child element not updating props after change in data coming from apollo in nuxt/vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-props

UPDATE: the main issue seems to be that the props only get updated once. They should change when this.campaign.name becomes available.

I want to dynamically update the title and breadcrumb data fields and show them on the page. Currently page page shows undefined or null. How can I fix this?

I tried to create a computed value but it only seems to update once (after head and breadcrumb data is already showed). A method does not work since I don't have anything to trigger the method.

What is the correct way to fix this?

I am using nuxt generate to deploy the app.

```
export default {
  components: { PageHeader },
  middleware: 'authenticated',
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Campaigns' + this.campaignName,
      breadcrumb: [
        {
          text: 'Campaigns',
          href: '/'
        },
        {
          text: this.campaignName,
          href: '/'
        }
      ],
      campaign: ''
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    campaign: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: campaignQuery,
      variables() {
        return { id: this.$route.params.id }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    campaignName() {
      return this.campaign && this.campaign.name
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is your apollo query 'campaign' actually returning something? Can you console.log() campaign or print it in the template? Remove campaign from your data element first.

Comment: yes I can see the object when I print it in the template, I think the issue is the apollo data is loaded after the title and breadcrumb data has already been set. e.g. ```this.campaign = { "id": "3", "name": "new postpaid", "description": null, "__typename": "Campaign" }```

Comment: or the values in the pageheader prop only get updated once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was putting the data elements directly as a computer property. (so no recalculation)

```
export default {
  components: { PageHeader },
  middleware: 'authenticated',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  apollo: {
    campaign: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: campaignQuery,
      variables() {
        return { id: this.$route.params.id }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.campaign && `Campaign: ${this.campaign.name}`
    },
    breadcrumb() {
      return [
        {
          text: 'Campaign',
          href: '/'
        },
        {
          text: this.campaign && this.campaign.name,
          href: '/'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your computed property `campaignName` returns `undefined` cuz `this.campaign.name` is not defined

```
campaignName() {
      if(this.campaign && this.campaign.name) return "Campaigns" + this.campaign.name;
      return "default value";
    }
```

Then you can use it directly in head

```
head() {
    return {
      title: this.campaignName
    }
  }
```

Comment: Still undefined when I try this. Also the campaign name output is not correct. Only for the title 'campaigns ' should be added.

Comment: If you do it correctly, anyway title must be "default value", did you put head title fixed string?